# Prove limit exists, unconvential method

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am looking at proving lim(log n! - (n + 1/2)logn + n) as n goes to infinity, exists. I have found that it is infinity.

I have solved this myself, but my friend said that he has a very interesting solution using the two hints below. I am not quite certain how he used these in his approach. Does anyone see how this is possible?

Hints:

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f(i)}= \int_{1}^{n+1}f(x) dx + \sum_{i=1}^{n}({f(i) - \int_{i}^{i+1}f(x) dx)}$, and I can let $f=log$.

I also know that

1+ 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n - logn

is positive, that it decreases as n increases, and hence that the sequence of these numbers converges to a limit between 0 and 1.

**EDIT: It seems that this depends on this problem, [Show that $\log(r)$ minus an integral involving the $\log$ function is less than $\frac{1}{6r^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452656/show-that-logr-minus-an-integral-involving-the-log-function-is-less-than)**

Still confused as to how this all ties together

Answer (score 0):

Your method can show that
the difference is bounded,
but it requires more work
to show that the limit exists.

It looks like your question
depends on the answer to
this question:

[Show that $\log(r)$ minus an integral involving the $\log$ function is less than $\frac{1}{6r^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452656/show-that-logr-minus-an-integral-involving-the-log-function-is-less-than)

From this,
using your sum-integral expression,
you can show that
$|\log n! - (n + 1/2)\log n + n|
$
is bounded,
since 
$\sum\frac1{n^2}$
converges.
However,
I do not think that
this level of analysis
will show that the limit exists.

I would be glad to be proved wrong.

Comment: hmmm yes it does seem to depend on that question, but I am not seeing how this all ties together nicely